# Reshetikhin-Turaev Invariant of Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics, knot-invariants

The [Reshetikhin-Turavev construction](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Reshetikhin-Turaev+construction) comes with an invariant that is sometimes called the Reshetikhin-Turaev Invariant.  I'm currently attempting to wrap my head around this construction but was hoping for a sneak peak to help motivate me.  My question is, what does the Reshetikhin-Turaev Invariant measure?  I mean, if it's an invariant of a space it must give you some information about the space itself right?

Comment: Maybe you will have more answers on MathOverflow.

Comment: The $sl(2)$ Reshetikhin-Turaev invariants of a $3$-manifold obtained from surgery on a link in $S^3$ are the colored Jones polynomials of the link.  There are some geometric interpretations of these polynomials at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176862/the-jones-polynomial-at-specific-values-of-t

Comment: @KyleMiller Interesting read.  Thanks!